# Impossible null pointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a real weird problem.
(Very important note: this is an example cause I can't paste the original code, I wrote it as text with no compiler.)  I have 2 classes:

```
class B {
    private int num = 9;

    public int getNum(){
       return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num){
       this.num = num;
    }
}

class A {
    private B b = new B();

    public void setB(B b){
        b.setNum(b != null? b.getNum() : 8);
   }

   public B getB(){
       if (b == null)
           System.out.println("How possible?");
       return b;
   }
}
```

Now, sometimes I get the print... but I don't see how's that possible.

A is a serialized class, but yet I can't figure it out.

Comment: Before each line in code, add four spaces.  This will make it display as code.

Comment: This code will not compile. Please post an example that will compile and show the error reproducibly.

Comment: The code still does not compile. For example, getB() return type should be B: public B getB()

Comment: You should _really really_ compile your code before. It's easy if you simply paste it into `A.java` and then run `javac A.java`. Saves everybody a lot of time.

Comment: University profs are notorious for writing code that doesn't compile. I suspect that this is homework.

Comment: @Axarydxa: ["The homework tag...is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Udi, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible, no.  You'll get a type error in the definition of `A.getB()` when you try to compile it, and your definition of `A.setB()` looks dubious as well (shadows `b`).

Comment: Indeed, should be `this.b.setNum(b != null? b.getNum() : 8);` - I've almost added this as an answer, you really should state that more clearly.

Comment: @Udi - you expect everyone to find your right errors, but ignore some errors. That's almost impossible. You don't know what your problem is - how can you be sure it's present in your sample code?

Comment: Im not expecting anyone to find anything in this code. The code is ment to make the question easier to undestand. I added the serialization issue. This is theoretical question

Comment: @udi: but you havent asked anything precise - what is the problem you are facing? how are you running/using this class? give more context for more answers.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few circumstances in which `b` might be null:

- reflection. `b` might be set to null reflectively, which circumvents your setter.
- custom serialisation. `b` might be explicitly restored as null. Alternatively, if `B` is not serialisable, you have it marked as transient to avoid errors and it's not restored.

---

To verify a simple serialisation workflow, use the following code:

```
    Object object = "someString";

    ByteArrayOutputStream holder = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new ObjectOutputStream(holder).writeObject(object);

    Object readObject = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(holder.toByteArray())).readObject();

    System.out.println(readObject);
```

where the first line is replaced by the actual object you wish to test

Comment: are you sure reflection "skips" setters? cause it does not skip default constructor as far as I know..

Comment: Reflection does not invoke any setters. Also, constructor invocation rules are a bit more complicated. The rule (IIRC) is that if you have a class hierarchy which contains both `Serializable` and non-`Serializable` classes, all constructors of non-serializable classes will *not* run.

Comment: Ok. So is there any wat for me to verify the problem is caused by reflection? I mean any method to override..? Or reflection changes the fields directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you manage to serialize an instance of `A` which has `b == null`, then you get a NPE. The reason is that during de-serialization, the constructor isn't invoked and therefore, `private B b = new B();` isn't run, so `b` stays `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you serialize the instance of A before adding the initialization of B to the class?
If that is the case you could get an instance of A where b is null because the constructors are not called (initializing a member of the class is part of the implicit constructor).
Then you will need to add an implementation of readObject() to class A there you can check whether or not b is null and initialize it if necessary.

Comment: Do you really mean `readResolve`? `readObject` would do as `b` is not final.

Answer (score 0):

This line won't compile either:

```
b.setNum(b != null? b.getNum : new B());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about this? If you give B as a parameter, why not use it?

```
class A {
    private B b = new B();

    public void setB(B b){
        if(b != null) {
            this.b = b;
        }
   }

   public B getB(){
       return b;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is never null! You assigned new B();

Comment: Who would do that? If you want to be sure, replace "this.b = b;" with "if(b != null) this.b = b;"

Comment: @rebugger: Please put that into your answer.

Comment: Why does it matter who would do that?! It is my class' logic, and beside I already mentioned that I can't paste my original code so that is a sample code (My original code makes a bit more sense)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: replace

```
System.out.println("How possible?");
```

with

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

That should make it easier for you to see what happened just before. Otherwise, without more information, the only things that seems a possible cause is the serialization.